# is_assignable and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, move, assignment-operator

[Here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/20_util/unique_ptr/dr2228.cc) is a test file from gcc, [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ygtnv3Zm1fMlc1zY)

```
struct do_nothing
{
    template <class T>
    void operator()(T*) {}
};

int
main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<int, do_nothing> p1(&i);
    std::unique_ptr<int> p2;
    static_assert(!std::is_assignable<decltype(p2), decltype(p1)>::value, ""); // note ! here.    
}
```

[`std::is_assignable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable)

> If the expression `std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>()` is well-formed in unevaluated context, provides the member constant value equal true. Otherwise, value is false. Access checks are performed as if from a context unrelated to either type.

[`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval):

```
template<class T>
typename std::add_rvalue_reference<T>::type declval() noexcept;
```

> The return type is `T&&` unless `T` is (possibly cv-qualified) void, in which case the return type is T.

Let's look at `MoveAssignOnly`:

```
struct MoveAssignOnly {
  MoveAssignOnly &operator=(MoveAssignOnly &) = delete;
  MoveAssignOnly &operator=(MoveAssignOnly &&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    static_assert(
    not std::is_assignable<MoveAssignOnly, MoveAssignOnly>::value, "");
}
```

[live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5vl6kQmmR0LJv8XP):

```
error: static_assert failed due to requirement '!std::is_assignable<MoveAssignOnly, MoveAssignOnly>::value'
```

Yes, **it fails to compile because it provides a move assignment**

Let's return to the [gcc's test file](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/testsuite/20_util/unique_ptr/dr2228.cc) and `std::unique_ptr`. As we know, [`std::unique_ptr` also has move assignments](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/memory#L321).

However, unlike `struct MoveAssignOnly`,  `static_assert(!std::is_assignable<decltype(p2), decltype(p1)>::value, "");`(more clearly, `static_assert(!std::is_assignable<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int, do_nothing>>::value, "");` compiles happily.

I have struggled with libcxx's implementation of `unique_ptr`  for long time, but still cannot figure out: how can `std::unique_ptr` be **not assignable**(`! is_assignable`) when `std::unique_ptr` provides move assignments?

Comment: [`std::unique_ptr` *is* assignable.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/252985f8163a4cab)

Comment: Your assignment corresponds to [line 2520](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/memory#L2520), not [line 2509](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/memory#L2509) of `memory` header. Note this SFINAE applied in template parameters: `class = _EnableIfDeleterAssignable<_Ep>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p1` and `p2` are of a different type. Unlike with `shared_ptr`, the deleter of a `unique_ptr` is part of the pointer's type. This means the move assignment operator does not allow you to assign (even move-assign) between two `unique_ptr`s if their deleter types differ.

`unique_ptr` also offers an assignment operator template which allows assigning from an rvalue of `unique_ptr` with a different deleter, but the deleters must be assignable (see [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D)). So you can make your static assert fire by making the deleters assignable:

```
struct do_nothing
{
    template <class T>
    void operator()(T*) {}

    template <class T>
    operator std::default_delete<T>() { return {}; }
};

int
main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<int, do_nothing> p1(&i);
    std::unique_ptr<int> p2;
    static_assert(!std::is_assignable<decltype(p2), decltype(p1)>::value, ""); // note ! here.    
}
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8667188dc6227c01)

Comment: There is an assignment operator for `std::unique_ptr` that accepts different type of deleter, but that different deleter must be _assignable_ into original deleter. See http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.asgn#6.3.

Comment: Thanks, you may be inserted with this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885538/why-does-move-constructor-affects-is-assignable