# Why does move constructor affect is_assignable?

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, move-constructor

Just came from [is_assignable and std::unique_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882498/is-assignable-and-stdunique-ptr). @Angew tells me that because `std::unique_ptr<int, do_nothing>` and `std::unique_ptr<int>` are different types, so `static_assert(not std::is_assignable<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int, do_nothing>>::value, "");`. So, I tried:

```
template<typename T, typename D>
struct MoveAssignOnly_V2
{
    MoveAssignOnly_V2&
    operator=(MoveAssignOnly_V2&)
        = delete;

    MoveAssignOnly_V2&
    operator=(MoveAssignOnly_V2&&) noexcept
    {}
};

int main()
{
      static_assert(not std::is_assignable_v<MoveAssignOnly_V2<int, float>,
                 MoveAssignOnly_V2<int, double>>);
}
```

Yes, because `MoveAssignOnly_V2<int, float>` and `MoveAssignOnly_V2<int, double>` are two different types, so **they are not assignable.**

**But**, when I add a a move ctor:

```
template<class U, class E>
MoveAssignOnly_V2(MoveAssignOnly_V2<U, E>&& m) noexcept {}
```

[**`static_assert` fail!**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D27yX2mvWYQphiKK)(both gcc and clang).

Question here: Why does move constructor affects is_assignable?

### Updated

The reason why I add this constructor is that I found `std::unique_ptr` have a

```
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u ) noexcept;
```

, which confuses me a little: how can it be not assignable now that it has such a ctor? so I tried add such ctor to `MoveAssignOnly_V2` and post this question. The two answers are fine, however, still cannot explain why `std::unique_ptr` is not assignable when it has both move assignment and this templated constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take this code:

```
MoveAssignOnly_V2<int, float> lhs;
MoveAssignOnly_V2<int, double> rhs;
lhs = stdL::move(rhs);
```

When the converting constructor (note that it's *not* a move constructor) is not there, there is no way to assign `rhs` into `lhs`.

However, when you add the constructor template, there is now a way to convert `rhs` into the type `MoveAssignOnly_V2<int, float>` (which creates a temporary of that type). Then, it's possible to move-assign from that temporary into `lhs`.

This is the same principle as:

```
double lhs = 3.14;
float rhs = 42.f;
lhs = std::move(rhs);
```

To address the update in the question:

You cannot go with function declarations alone, you have to read the full specification (in the standard or [suitable reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr)). Quoting the linked reference about the converting constructor of `std::unique_ptr`:

> This constructor only participates in overload resolution if all of the following is true:
>
> a) `unique_ptr<U, E>::pointer` is implicitly convertible to `pointer`
> b) `U` is not an array type
> c) Either `Deleter` is a reference type and `E` is the same type as `D`, or `Deleter` is not a reference type and `E` is implicitly convertible to `D`

So as you can see, the `unique_ptr`'s converting constructor must be implemented so that it's only active if the source deleter can be converted to the target one. That's basically the same rule as for move assignment in the previous question.

Comment: please take a look at updates in the question. I noticed unique_ptr also has such converting constructor, however, unlike `MoveAssignOnly_V2`, unique_ptr is still not assignable.

Answer (score 2):

What you added here:

```
template<class U, class E>
MoveAssignOnly_V2(MoveAssignOnly_V2<U, E>&& m) noexcept {}
```

is not only a move constructor, but a templated constructor that can construct `MoveAssignOnly_V2<T, D>` from any `MoveAssignOnly_V2<U, E>`.

Thus constructing `MoveAssignOnly_V2<int, float>` from `MoveAssignOnly_V2<int, double>>` is fine.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not a move constructor at all.

Comment: You might want to call it a conversion constructor, which allows the conversion to a type that is assignable.